# ActiveX textbox shows previous entry

Tags: excel

Apologies for not showing my code but after much trial and error I'm thinking the issue I describe could possibly be a textbox property issue rather than coding error or ommission. The code itself works as it should but there is a phenomenom which frustratingly persists.

On a wsheet amongst a number of ActiveX controls I have a textbox and 2 images. They are used for a search function. As you would expect the textbox is for user entry and the images are for 'run search' and 'erase search'. I set the search text as a string.

My issue is when hitting either 'run search' OR 'erase search' the textbox momentarily shows the previous text string. I have set this previous string to "" all over but without success.

This is best observed when setting a search text which will knowingly fail.
The sequence is...
1) Enter 'XXXX' to search
2) Hit 'run search'
3) Search code executes
4) Prior to textbox narrative returning "XXXX not found" it momentarily shows the previous entry, say "AAAA", before returning the correct result.

How can this be prevented?

EDIT
With no response I posted this on Jon Peltier's site at https://peltiertech.com/forms-controls-and-activex-controls-in-excel/#comment-1481602
Kindly he tested and concluded "It looks like an ActiveX thing, and I guess you’re stuck with it."
From tests this phenomenon occurs even when selecting any cell, not only the image controls. In other words it is triggered as soon as the textbox loses focus. Arguably, because it is a momentary change it does not seem possible to trap the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar problem and raised a question myself, but managed to have more luck in getting some responses, see:
[After setting ActiveX textbox to empty value, previous text briefly appears in box before disappearing again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266970/after-setting-activex-textbox-to-empty-value-previous-text-briefly-appears-in-b)

Through the help of the responders I was able to create a work around using Application.SendKeys. Possibly one of the answers might be able to help you in getting around this issue.

For me personally Application.SendKeys was required as this overwrote the value in the text box and refreshed it meaning the previous value was no longer present. For completeness here is a snippet of the code I used:

```vb
    'Select text box to update
    Sheet1.userName.Activate

    DoEvents
    'Replace value with ""
    Sheet1.userName.Application.SendKeys ("")

    'Copy above for other textboxes on sheet
    Sheet1.emailAddr.Activate

    DoEvents
    Sheet1.emailAddr.Application.SendKeys ("")
    'Change text box currently active to force change values to take place
    Sheet1.userName.Activate
```

I am selecting my text boxes one at a time then using SendKeys("") as a way to emulate the user deleting the current field in the box, after that I switch back to another text box as this is needed to force the refresh of the value.

Being able to force the text boxes to be blank after I was done with the values meant that there were no previous values that could inadvertently appear later on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Skenworthy for your suggestion. Over time I kept returning to my issue but without success however your code has formed the basis of a solution.
I only had 1 textbox used as a search input plus 2 buttons, 1 to begin search and the other to clear.
My solution was to create a hidden dummy textbox and each time I wished to make a comment in the search textbox I would use sendkeys to the dummy box. However that was not the final code. Switching focus between the 3 controls became too complex given the type of potential user errors that could be made. So I abandoned the Begin search button relying instead on the Enterkey and the Clear search button.
Now each time I need to return a response message I use the code below immediately prior to clear the search textbox. It has consistently worked without flaw. So, a long time coming, my specific solution seems so simple in hindsight but thank you again for the pointer.

```
Sub RemovePrevText()

''' use dummy txtbox to clear old message from SearchInput
With Sheets(1)
    .txtDummy.Activate
    DoEvents
    .txtDummy.Application.SendKeys ("")
End With

 End Sub
```