# After setting ActiveX textbox to empty value, previous text briefly appears in box before disappearing again

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex

I created a data entry form on a spreadsheet using ActiveX TextBoxes. These are coupled with a submit details button and a clear data button. Both buttons at the end of execution set the text boxes back to blank to be refilled by the next user.

After the boxes are set to "", when the user begins filling the form each time the user selects one of the text boxes the previous entry details briefly appear in the text box then disappear.

This is a quite frustrating issue as I am trying to make it so the previous users details are hidden.

I searched many articles on the best way to set text boxes to empty and it seems that the main way is to set the .text property to "". There seems to be no mention of this behavior.

```
Sub clearForm()
'    Worksheets("Student Data").userName.Text = ""
'    Worksheets("Student Data").emailAddr.Text = ""
'    Worksheets("Student Data").contactNum.Text = ""
'    Worksheets("Student Data").Course.Text = ""
'    Worksheets("Student Data").gradDate.Text = ""
'    Worksheets("Student Data").addComment.Text = ""

    textbox1clear
End Sub

Sub submitData()
    'Code here that takes users entered data and outputs to hidden and protected sheet    

    'After data copied text boxes are cleared of users information, same as above sub
    Worksheets("Student Data").userName.Text = ""
    Worksheets("Student Data").emailAddr.Text = ""
    Worksheets("Student Data").contactNum.Text = ""
    Worksheets("Student Data").Course.Text = ""
    Worksheets("Student Data").gradDate.Text = ""
    Worksheets("Student Data").addComment.Text = ""
End Sub

Sub textbox1clear()
    Dim sel
    sel = Selection.Address
    Sheet1.userName.Activate
    Application.SendKeys ("Test ")
    Sheet1.userName.Value = ""
    Range(sel).Activate
End Sub
```

Expected - Text boxes should be clear of data ready for next user.

Actual - Text boxes are clear until user selects them to begin entering data at which point previous entry briefly appears in the box and disappears again.

Comment: Try setting to `vbNullString `

Comment: @0m3r Unfortunately this has the same problem, previous text still flashes in the text boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common textbox behaviour. Unless the textbox is selected again, the changes aren't actually completed. I can see how this is inconvenient if used by other users and data entered is confidential. After numerous tests, the only working way I found around this is to trigger this flicker after clearing by making VBA select and deselect the input box, and simulating new user input with sendkeys.

```
Sub textbox1clear()
Dim sel
sel = Selection.Address
Sheet1.TextBox1.Activate
Application.Sendkeys(" ")
Sheet1.TextBox1.Value = ""
Range(sel).Activate
End Sub
```

I have built in a selection recall to make it (slightly) more seamless if the sub is called with a button. However if this is omitted and no selection is made after this sub is ran, the text will flicker again when the textbox is deselected.

Also note this should always be called manually, if it is called from a `Textbox_LostFocus` like I did, it will enter a continuous loop as long as the textbox isn't selected.

It's not a very elegant solution, but if data protection is priority, it will do the trick.

If this is not sufficient, you might want to [hide your input altogether](https://logicallyproven.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-hide-password-text-in-textbox.html) if this is an option.

Comment: Sad to hear it is common behaviour and thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately it doesnt seem to be applying to the Text Boxes, also tried .CalculateFull and .CalculateRebuild that I looked up as others ways to force the sheet to recalculate but they also havent seemed to have done the trick.

Comment: Hmmm that's unfortunate as it seemed to have done the trick in my tests. I'll see if I can find an alternative, but I make no promises.

Comment: @Skenworthy Did some very vigorous trying and testing and found a fairly working method. it's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for the update, definitely along the right lines, tested it several times and it has limited the amount of times that it is happening but still occassionally is visible when selecting the text box, will continue to test and check whether any additions to this could reduce it further

Comment: @Skenworthy My original idea was to use `application.sendkeys(" ")` to simulate a new user entry and absolutely overwrite what was in the cell. I found it was a bit overkill as the above already works, but it sounds like you might need it.

Comment: Would be worth a try at this point, dumb question but what would the syntax be to use sendkeys with the text boxes, currently adding it in is only writing to the selected cell.

Comment: @Skenworthy updated my answer. If this doesn't work I don't know what will.

Comment: That was the syntax that I was using, but to be sure swapped it out with yours but it just sends the keys to the cell that was selected before the user clicked into the text box

Comment: Not sure how you managed that, as there's a `Textbox1.Activate` right before it, meaning it can only be active. Can you update your question with your current code and I'll take a look?

Comment: Neither do I, hence my confusion and asking the question, have updated with my code

Comment: Hmmm if it doesn't work perhaps using `sendkeys` isn't the right solution. Can't find a proper way to make it interact with excel objects anyway since it's mostly considered a redundant function. Sorry I couldn't help more, but I'll come back if I come up with something else!

Comment: Turns out the sendkeys was sending to the active text box then overwriting that call and sending to the next active object, in this case the selected cell. I decided to add in sendkeys("") for each textbox then switch to a different text box, sendkeys to that one and then switch back to the previous one, really odd work around but it has worked! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

you could use a *quite long* string made of "spaces" and then substitute them with a single "space"

```
Public Sub clearForm()
    Worksheets("Student Data").userName.Text = "                                " 'vbNullString
    Worksheets("Student Data").userName.Text = vbNullString
End Sub
```

make sure that *quite long* is enough for your textbox to be covered

Or

you could use a "dummy/informative" text to be removed right after entering the textbox for a subsequent input

```
Public Sub clearForm()
    Worksheets("Student Data").userName.Text = "cleared"
    …. (rest of your code
End Sub

Private Sub userName_GotFocus()
    With Worksheets("Student Data").userName
        If .Text = "cleared" Then .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub emailAddr_GotFocus()
    With Worksheets("Student Data").emailAddr
        If .Text = "cleared" Then .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub
```

… (and so on for all your textboxes)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of your suggestion stopped the user entered texting from being visible when the user focuses on that text box. Thank you for the suggestion though, thought the placeholder method you recommended would have been a good workaround.

Comment: @Skenworthy, you are welcome. too bad they don't work for you. In my test they both worked, though